# HTTP get request with basic authentication in Angular2 not working

Tags: javascript, angular, get, request, basic-authentication

I'm trying to make a get request with basic authentication to read a list from [MailChimp](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/). I do get it running with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), but not in my Angular2 app.

This is my request:

```
this.http
    .get(
        `${this.MC_API_URL}/lists`,
        {
            headers: new Headers({
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('any:' + this.MC_API_KEY)
            })
        }
    )
    .subscribe(__response => log(__response.json()))
;
```

The chrome console throws back [501 Not implemented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error).

What's wrong?

Comment: What kind of URL is this one `${this.MC_API_URL}/lists`?

Comment: Routes to the MailChimp API v3 - something like `https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0`.